# How to make Python dump lines of text from web?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

How can I create program that will take lines from the website. User needs to specify how much lines he will take from the website, and he has like limit (1000), and also he has a cooldown like every 24 hours you can capture data from web.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read about how to create a [Minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What have you researched and tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a **web crawler/spider/scraper**.

Try to use Scrapy as it is described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-crawl-a-web-page-with-scrapy-and-python-3).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at web-scraping library like scrappy to get your data from a website and parsing library like beautifulsoup to make sense of it. To trigger it every 24h you can use a hosting like Heroku with some custom logic, depending on what you wanr.